# How to set image in background of frame in html

Tags: html

I have divided frame into two and want to set background image. Please assist.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <frameset rows="10%,*">
            <frame src ="OK2.jpg">  
            <frame src ="OK3.jpg"> 
        </frameset>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please show your code and what you have tried.

Comment: make 2 seperate html pages and set their background and use those html pages in frame
 <frameset rows="10%,*">
            <frame src ="page1.html">  
            <frame src ="page2.html"> 
        </frameset>

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you shouldn't use Frames at all. They're old and depreciated, you ought to use < divs >

But anyway, if you are using frames on html, you can't add a background image to it since each frame is a separate document.

But you can sorta make it work, like so, In CSS for your page :

```
body {
    background-image: url('path/to/image.jpg');
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: If my answer helped you, please set it as an accepted answer. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Frameset and frame can link only to html page to work properly. Set two different background using tow different html page.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <frameset rows="10%,*">
            <frame src ="back01.htm">  
            <frame src ="back02.htm"> 
       </frameset>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now create the two page (change only the background image name)

```
<html>
    <body style="background: url('OK2.jpg') no-repeat;">

    </body>
</html>
```